# How to calculate Camera “correct” position and distance to Frame all my Scene?

Tags: unity, mathematics, trigonometry

Consider I have N dynamic points on my Scene, I would like to "frame" all them, with my Camera.

[image]

How can i calculate (at runtime) Vector3 Position to correctly frame all my scene ?

This is my idea:

- Calculate Avarage for all my points
- Move my Camera "up" / Zoom out to correctly "frame" all my points (i don't know how to calculate )
- Use Unity LookAt(myAvaragePoint)

I think i've to use some trigonometryc function to calculate the Y Camera position (to zoom in, zoom out), but i don't know which!

Thanks